# Missing Woocommerce add to cart button

Tags: woocommerce

please help my add to cart button is missing
Site:http://emceecouture.com/shop/mc728/#.Uwx05fSSz1g
I really have no idea where to retrieve it back

Answer (score 0):

simplest workaround is to change class of div containing product quantity and add to cart button (`/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`).

i.e. from

```
<div class="single_variation_wrap">
```

to

```
<div class="single_variation_wrap_mod">
```

to fool js which is adding `style="display:none"` even when you remove it from html code.

I can't understand why woocommerce developers decided to hide this button and add js to show it after someone selects variation, rather than (as every other ecommerce on the planet) show add to cart button, and focus on the attributes if someone haven't selected one.

IMHO this is an UX fail.